# Inline Documentation displays 'Cannot find macro' for List.head()

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, javadoc

Inline Documentation (use `Ctrl+Q` to open it's pop-up) in IntelliJ IDEA (2016.3.4) is having problems when JavaDoc contains variables, like:

```
/** Selects the first element of this $coll.
 *  $orderDependent
 *  @return  the first element of this $coll.
 *  @throws NoSuchElementException if the $coll is empty.
 */
```

Instead of parsing these variables it displays: `[Cannot find macro: $coll.]`. Scala [API](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#head:A) parses it correctly and changes `$coll` into `iterable collection`.

Is there a way to fix this issue in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known bug in IntelliJ IDEA Scala plug-in:

- [SCL-9720](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9720) Documentation view unreadable when @define placeholders are used